# Could not cast value of type 'SwiftyJSON.JSON' to 'Swift.String'

Tags: ios, json, swift3, swifty-json

I have been trying to display data parsed from JSON to a `UITableView`.
I used `SwiftyJSON` to parse the data and then pass the array to another controller.

I used `NSArray` to force the JSON to an array. When I print the passed data, it shows up as the following:

```
(
    "string one",
    "string two"
)
```

Then inside the

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

function, I used

```
let urls: String = sshoString[indexPath.item] as! String
```

When I print the array inside the function `cellForItemAt` without forcing the type to be a String, it prints the following:

```
string one
string two
```

but when I force the type to be String it crashes and shows the following:

```
Could not cast the value of type 'SwiftyJSON.JSON'  to 'Swift.String'.
```

How to make that work? How to force it to be a String?

**AS REQUESTED:**

```
var featuredScreenshots:NSArray = NSArray()
var featuredssho = NSMutableArray()

for items in json["featured"].arrayValue {
    featuredssho.add(items["screenshots"].arrayValue)
}

self.featuredScreenshots = featuredssho as NSArray
```

then I passed it to the other controller:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsView") as! DetailsView

vc.sshoString = featuredScreenshots[indexPath.row] as! NSArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing an element of a JSON in SwiftyJSON returns a type `JSON`.

In order to get the type you are looking for, you need to use the included properties of the JSON type like so:

```
let urls: String = sshoString[indexPath.item].string!
```

With SwiftyJSON `.string` is of optional type `String?`, which is why I left the force unwrap there. In general, force unwraps should be avoided, so I would recommend doing something along these lines:

```
if let urls = sshoString[indexPath.item].string {
    //urls is now type String, and you can use it as needed
}
```

I recommend reviewing the documentation for [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), as it goes into more detail and shows other examples using `.int`, `.bool`, `.url`, etc to get the values you are looking for.

Comment: it says 'value of Any has no member of string', i have no idea how it became Any as i have passed it to the other controller as an `NSArray` then wrap it again as an `NSArray`

Comment: I have really digged into SwiftyJSON docs, but nothing mentioned about forcing Json array to be a string with indexPath

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code where you create the actual array. You may have inadvertently created nested arrays. SwiftyJSON also has .array so you might try doing sshoString[0].array[indexPath.item].string

Comment: Are you trying to print all elements in the array as one string?

Comment: i have updated the question with the code where i create the actual array, and by the way it looks like the following in the Json file               `"screenshots": [
                "string one",
                "string two"
              ]`

Comment: going to invite you to a chat as there's a lot going on here

Comment: This user is very smart that he kinda figured my whole code by the few snippets i gave, he was very smart and helpful. thanks for helping and thanks for being patient with me as i'm still new to Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , it happens sometimes that you need to assign a JSON value to a standard type value like String or Dictionary ,,,etc . Basically as described above and according to swiftyJson documentation , it has its own way of converting like .dicitonary , .stringvalue,,,etc. ***But the issue is that compiler can't read the value we are assigning as a JSON type at compile time*** so merely cast it as a JSON then  use swiftyJson way of satisfying needed value type , EX:

Struct NormalStringName

{

var name : String!

}

and we have **nameValue** parsed from backend or wherever with swiftyJSON so to assign **nameValue** to our struct instance which expects normal string we do this :

_ = NormalStringName(name:(**nameValue** as! JSON).stringValue

Hope this helps and please ask if not clear .